# Want to find the max value from each array of arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I want the max value from the each array:

```
[array([[0.64104085 0.2695865  0.12760413],
[0.20816632 0.72728643 0.23365428],[0.52334888 0.83298642 0.43656896], dtype=float32)]
```

output:

```
[array([[0.64104085],[0.72728643],[0.83298642], dtype=float32)]
```

My code is the following:

```
def find_max(arr):
    #find maximum value
    max_value = np.array([])
    for i, j in zip(arr,range(len(arr))):
        max_val = np.array(max(i))
        max_value = np.append(max_value, max_val)
    return[max_value]

import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(9).reshape(3,3)
print(arr)
find_max(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `np.reshape`

```
res = np.max(a, axis=1).reshape(a.shape[0], -1)
```

Using list comprehension

```
res = np.array([[x] for x in np.max(a, axis=1)])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.64104085]
 [0.72728643]
 [0.83298642]]
```

Comment: Thanks for kind response output of your code is: [0.64104085 0.72728643 0.83298642]

but i want [[0.64104085], [0.72728643], [0.83298642]]

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, i am able to find the max value from each array. but i want output in different form. which is:
[array([[0.64104085],[0.72728643],[0.83298642], dtype=float32)]